# firebase cloud function not updating the data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have firebase real-time database which has user node and contains many users I want to set `rating` property of user to 0, for that first I need to read the database and the update the database.

my function is reading the data but unable to update and return  `{}` on the browser

```
exports.quarter = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 let user1 = admin.database().ref('users/user1/userDetails').once('value');
 let user2 = admin.database().ref('users/user2/userDetails').once('value');
 let user3 = admin.database().ref('users/user3/userDetails').once('value');
 let user4 = admin.database().ref('users/user4/userDetails').once('value');
  Promise.all([user1, user2, user3, user4])
      .then(result => {
    let data = {};
     result[0].forEach(action => {
         data['users/user1/userDetails/' + action.key + '/' + 'Rating'] = 0;
     });
     result[1].forEach(action => {
         data['users/user2/userDetails/' + action.key + '/' + 'Rating'] = 0;
     });
    result[2].forEach(action => {
        data['users/user3/userDetails/' + action.key + '/' + 'Rating'] = 0;
    });
    result[3].forEach(action => {
        data['users/user4/userDetails/' + action.key + '/' + 'Rating'] = 0;
    });
     return data;

}).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
     return  admin.database().ref().update(data);

 }).then(data => {
     return res.send('done');

 }).catch(error => {
    return res.status(500).send(error);
 })
});
```

I can see the result of `console.log(data)` but the function is not updating and finally after performing get request it's returning `{}`.

what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

this line `admin.database().ref().update(data)` your reference seems to be `undefined`, take a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

I'm not sure if you mean something like keeping the ref you defined at top

```
 let user1 = admin.database().ref('users/user1/userDetails').once('value');
```

if that is the case.. you have to something like

```
 let user1 = admin.database().ref('users/user1/userDetails');
  user1.once('value')

 // and down where you want to update
 user1.update.(data)
```

But notice this is only the data for that node imparticular, you can not update em all at once if you want to use your approach

Comment: then how do I get the reference to the root node?

Comment: not sure what you mean by root node, `users` maybe?

Comment: yeah, but I want the parent of `users`, I have included users in the data variable.

Comment: beyond `users` node it is the name of the project in the firebase console.

Comment: then you need to ref that node you are mentioning, check what you are doing here for example `let user1 = admin.database().ref('users/user1/userDetails')` you are defining the path 'users/user1/userDetails', you have to do the same for updating writing, basically tell where to save

Comment: but before `users` node there is no parent node, and I don't want to go into the `users` node.  according to you should I use path '\'  or `' '`to get the absolute parent

Comment: are u sure you want to update then? probably it's `set` the method u are looking for, read the docs, the section for the update method

Comment: yes, it is `update`,  because user contains other data that I don't want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all()` is returning before any of the promises passed to it are going to finish.  This means `data` is going to be an empty object has original defined, and that value is returned immediately.  Instead you should have the following `then` callback handle each result:

```
exports.quarter = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 let user1 = admin.database().ref('users/user1/userDetails').once('value');
 let user2 = admin.database().ref('users/user2/userDetails').once('value');
 let user3 = admin.database().ref('users/user3/userDetails').once('value');
 let user4 = admin.database().ref('users/user4/userDetails').once('value');
 return Promise.all([user1, user2, user3, user4]);
}).then(data => {
  // data will be an array of all the results. Handle them here.
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
exports.quarter = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let user1 = admin
    .database()
    .ref('users/user1/userDetails')
    .once('value');
  let user2 = admin
    .database()
    .ref('users/user2/userDetails')
    .once('value');
  let user3 = admin
    .database()
    .ref('users/user3/userDetails')
    .once('value');
  let user4 = admin
    .database()
    .ref('users/user4/userDetails')
    .once('value');

  Promise.all([user1, user2, user3, user4])
    .then(result => {
      let data = {};
      result[0].forEach(action => {
        data['users/user1/userDetails/' + action.key + '/' + 'Rating'] = 0;
      });
      result[1].forEach(action => {
        data['users/user2/userDetails/' + action.key + '/' + 'Rating'] = 0;
      });
      result[2].forEach(action => {
        data['users/user3/userDetails/' + action.key + '/' + 'Rating'] = 0;
      });
      result[3].forEach(action => {
        data['users/user4/userDetails/' + action.key + '/' + 'Rating'] = 0;
      });
      console.log(data);
      return admin
        .database()
        .ref()
        .update(data);
    })
    .then(() => {
      return res.send('done');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: @rahulKushwaha Did you have time to look at the proposed solution?